# Android SHA1 for Phonegap Developer App

Tags: android, ios, cordova, phonegap

I want to test Google+ login inside the Phonegap Developer app but I need to generate a SHA1.

I want to avoid building it into Android Studio whilst it's still being developed. So wondering if there is a way to get a key that is compatible with the Phonegap developer app installed on my phone?

This is the app i mean: https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.adobe.phonegap.app&hl=en_GB